# Manipulating Microsoft Word document without using Interop

Tags: ms-word

1. Is there any alternatives to manipulate Microsoft Word document (2003 and above) without using Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies ?
2. Is it possible to manipulate Microsoft Word document using native .NET assemblies without using COM ?
3. Is there any third party components that provide native manipulation of the Microsoft Word document ?

Comment: Are you talking about binary Word documents (.doc) or OpenXML Word documents (.docx/.docm)?

Comment: My objective is to manipulate binary word documents (.doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aspose

DocID

OfficeWriter

Windward reports

TXText

The OpenXML sdk (for the new XML office file formats anyway)

All decent tools, they each have pluses and minuses though, just depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. For 2003 I'd say no, for 2007+ you can use XML
2. Again for 2003 I'd say no, for 2007+ you can use XML thus .Net can be used
3. Sorry don't know and would reckon no